# Filter a string in Groovy and do something with the matches

Tags: regex, groovy, devops, jenkins-groovy

```
 def aString = '[Something-26607] Updating another.txt [Something2] Updating something.txt [Something2] Updating something.txt fsfsfs'
```

Is there a way in groovy to get only unique  parts between the square brackets and store them in a variable so after I can call them in a for loop. So I will iterate over them

```
Something-26607
Something2
```

I have tried:

```
def matcher = aString =~ (/\[(?<issue>[^]]+)]/)
def result = matcher.find() ? matcher.group('issue') : ""
 print result
```

but I get only get the first match:

```
Something-26607
```

Comment: You can run `while (matcher.find()) {` and use a pattern like `String regex = "\\[(?<issue>[^]]+)](?!.*\\1)";` to find the unique matches in the string, or use your original pattern and use a Set for example. The values are in group 1 of the pattern.

Comment: Can you give an example. I can't fully understand what you are saying

Comment: An example of the pattern https://regex101.com/r/6mqnnR/1 as an example https://ideone.com/3yeGUi

Comment: ah I see the java way

Comment: Would this be better? https://ideone.com/CZO97s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience in Groovy, but reading a little bit about the syntax to get an example, you might use a Set and loop the results using a while loop:

```
def myList = []
def aString = '[Something-26607] Updating another.txt [Something2] Updating something.txt [Something2] Updating something.txt fsfsfs'

def pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[(?<issue>[^]]+)]")
def matcher = pattern.matcher(aString)

while (matcher.find()) {
    myList << matcher.group(1)
}
println myList.toSet()
```

Output

```
[Something2, Something-26607]
```

[Groovy demo](https://ideone.com/CZO97s)

Without using a Set, you can also use a negative lookahead to check to get the unique values in the string asserting that what is captured in the group does not occur anymore at the right side.

```
\\[(?<issue>[^]]+)](?!.*\\1)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6mqnnR/1/)